# Make Javascript fetch results clickable

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, fetch

I am a beginner in Javascript and got the following problem. I got a JSON file that I'm using to fetch data. Now I want to make the search results clickable, so they will appear in the input field. Later it should be included in a card where I can save all the inputs.

This the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Test Async</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
                    <h3 class="text-center mb-3">Flights</h3>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter IATA Code, or Airport">
                    </div>
                    <div id="match-list"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the JS

```
// Get Elements
const search = document.querySelector('#search');
const matchList = document.querySelector('#match-list');

// Searc JSON Airport file
const searchFlights = async searchText => {
    const response = await fetch('airports.json');
    const data = await response.json();

    // Filter Data with regex
    let results = data.filter(result => {
        const regexIata = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');
        const regexName = new RegExp(`${searchText}`, 'gi');
        if (result.name != null) {
            return result.iata.match(regexIata) || result.name.match(regexName);
        }
    });

    if (searchText.length === 0) {
        matches = []; // Empty array if no result
        matchList.innerHTML = ''; // Shows nothing when serachbar is empty
    }

    else {
        outputHtml(results);
    }
};

const outputHtml = results => {
    if(results.length > 0) {
        const html = results.map(match =>
            `<div class="card card-body mb-1">
                <a href="#" class="data-input"><h6>${match.iata} | ${match.name}</h6></a>
            </div>`).join('');

        matchList.innerHTML = html;
    }
};

// Event listern on any event, can also be key up, down or whatever
search.addEventListener('input', () => searchFlights(search.value));
```

A small sample of the JSON file (real one has over 6000 entries)

````
[
    {
        "iata": "UTK",
        "lon": "169.86667",
        "iso": "MH",
        "status": 1,
        "name": "Utirik Airport",
        "continent": "OC",
        "type": "airport",
        "lat": "11.233333",
        "size": "small"
    },
    {
        "iata": "FIV",
        "iso": "US",
        "status": 1,
        "name": "Five Finger CG Heliport",
        "continent": "NA",
        "type": "heliport",
        "size": null
    },
    {
        "iata": "FAK",
        "iso": "US",
        "status": 1,
        "name": "False Island Seaplane Base",
        "continent": "NA",
        "type": "seaplanes",
        "size": null
    },
    {
        "iata": "BWS",
        "iso": "US",
        "status": 0,
        "name": "Blaine Municipal Airport",
        "continent": "NA",
        "type": "closed",
        "size": null
    },
    {
        "iata": "WKK",
        "lon": "-158.61111",
        "iso": "US",
        "status": 1,
        "name": "Aleknagik \/ New Airport",
        "continent": "NA",
        "type": "airport",
        "lat": "59.27778",
        "size": "medium"
    },
    {
        "iata": "TSS",
        "iso": "US",
        "status": 1,
        "name": "East 34th Street Heliport",
        "continent": "NA",
        "type": "heliport",
        "size": null
    },
    {
        "iata": "FOB",
        "lon": "-123.79444",
        "iso": "US",
        "status": 1,
        "name": "Fort Bragg Airport",
        "continent": "NA",
        "type": "airport",
        "lat": "39.474445",
        "size": "small"
    },
    {
        "iata": "ABP",
        "lon": "141.1",
        "iso": "PG",
        "status": 1,
        "name": "Atkamba Airport",
        "continent": "OC",
        "type": "airport",
        "lat": "-6.066667",
        "size": "small"
    },
    {
        "iata": "ALV",
        "iso": "AD",
        "status": 1,
        "name": "Andorra la Vella Heliport",
        "continent": "EU",
        "type": "heliport",
        "size": null
    },
    {
        "iata": "ADC",
        "lon": "145.73334",
        "iso": "PG",
        "status": 1,
        "name": "Andakombe Airport",
        "continent": "OC",
        "type": "airport",
        "lat": "-7.133333",
        "size": "small"
    },
    {
        "iata": "TJP",
        "lon": "-66.563545",
        "iso": "PR",
        "status": 1,
        "name": "Areopuerto Internacional Michael Gonzalez",
        "continent": "NA",
        "type": "airport",
        "lat": "18.010702",
        "size": "large"
    },
    {
        "iata": "AEE",
        "iso": "SS",
        "status": 1,
        "name": "Adareil Airport",
        "continent": "AF",
        "type": "airport",
        "size": "small"
    },
    {
        "iata": "AEI",
        "iso": "ES",
        "status": 1,
        "name": "Algeciras Heliport",
        "continent": "EU",
        "type": "heliport",
        "size": null
    }
]
```
Thanks a lot in advance
````

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target....){}
)
```

to add event for dynamic element, ant it better to use `setTimeout` in input event so if user type 10 chars within `xx milisecond` it will only send the request to server only once.

```js
// Get Elements
const search = document.querySelector('#search');
const matchList = document.querySelector('#match-list');

// Searc JSON Airport file
const searchFlights = async searchText => {
    //const response = await fetch('airports.json');
    //const data = await response.json();
    const data = [{"iata":"UTK","lon":"169.86667","iso":"MH","status":1,"name":"Utirik Airport","continent":"OC","type":"airport","lat":"11.233333","size":"small"},{"iata":"FIV","iso":"US","status":1,"name":"Five Finger CG Heliport","continent":"NA","type":"heliport","size":null},{"iata":"FAK","iso":"US","status":1,"name":"False Island Seaplane Base","continent":"NA","type":"seaplanes","size":null},{"iata":"BWS","iso":"US","status":0,"name":"Blaine Municipal Airport","continent":"NA","type":"closed","size":null},{"iata":"WKK","lon":"-158.61111","iso":"US","status":1,"name":"Aleknagik \/ New Airport","continent":"NA","type":"airport","lat":"59.27778","size":"medium"},{"iata":"TSS","iso":"US","status":1,"name":"East 34th Street Heliport","continent":"NA","type":"heliport","size":null},{"iata":"FOB","lon":"-123.79444","iso":"US","status":1,"name":"Fort Bragg Airport","continent":"NA","type":"airport","lat":"39.474445","size":"small"},{"iata":"ABP","lon":"141.1","iso":"PG","status":1,"name":"Atkamba Airport","continent":"OC","type":"airport","lat":"-6.066667","size":"small"},{"iata":"ALV","iso":"AD","status":1,"name":"Andorra la Vella Heliport","continent":"EU","type":"heliport","size":null},{"iata":"ADC","lon":"145.73334","iso":"PG","status":1,"name":"Andakombe Airport","continent":"OC","type":"airport","lat":"-7.133333","size":"small"},{"iata":"TJP","lon":"-66.563545","iso":"PR","status":1,"name":"Areopuerto Internacional Michael Gonzalez","continent":"NA","type":"airport","lat":"18.010702","size":"large"},{"iata":"AEE","iso":"SS","status":1,"name":"Adareil Airport","continent":"AF","type":"airport","size":"small"},{"iata":"AEI","iso":"ES","status":1,"name":"Algeciras Heliport","continent":"EU","type":"heliport","size":null}]

    // Filter Data with regex
    let results = data.filter(result => {
        const regexIata = new RegExp(`^${searchText}`, 'gi');
        const regexName = new RegExp(`${searchText}`, 'gi');
        if (result.name != null) {
            return result.iata.match(regexIata) || result.name.match(regexName);
        }
    });

    if (searchText.length === 0) {
        matches = []; // Empty array if no result
        matchList.innerHTML = ''; // Shows nothing when serachbar is empty
    }

    else {
        outputHtml(results);
    }
};

const outputHtml = results => {
    if(results.length > 0) {
        const html = results.map(match =>
            `<div class="card card-body mb-1">
                <h6 class="data-input">${match.iata} | ${match.name}</h6>
            </div>`).join('');

        matchList.innerHTML = html;
    }
};

// Event listern on any event, can also be key up, down or whatever
let timer;
search.addEventListener('input', () => {
  if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(searchFlights, 300, search.value);
});

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('data-input')){
    search.value = e.target.textContent;
    document.querySelector('#match-list').innerHTML = "";
  }
});
```

```css
.data-input {cursor: pointer;color: blue;}
.data-input:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
      <h3 class="text-center mb-3">Flights</h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter IATA Code, or Airport" />
      </div>
      <div id="match-list"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```